# How to print html code so that i wrote it only once?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working at a web application and i am doing some refactoring.

Doing so, anyway, i was caught in a dilemma: i have some similar nor identical parts in my pages that i want to compress in just one in order to make some edits just once, since edits are becoming a pain.

But how to do so? I am working with php, js and jquery.

Doing it with php echos is a big no; it's really difficult to manage all the brackets and anyway it doesn't look like to me the most elegant solution, plus, i need to do some control over the things i print.

I was thinking something about functions, but since i have no much experience i don't really know where i can hit my head. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: i was asked some examples.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" class="big" style="display:none;">
<h3> Insert Contact </h3>
    <fieldset class="col2">
    <!-- Some inputs here -->
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clean Form">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="insert" value="1" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="modify" value="1" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="secret" value="<? echo($perm); ?>" class="hidden">
</form>
```

This, for example, is a form that i want to add in some pages. In some other i don't want. But, for example i need, depending on the page that made the call, to toggle some parameters or change some values, that is a thing that i don't think i can do with php includes.

Comment: Have you looked at including files with PHP's `include()`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: So add common files that have methods that you can call.

Comment: I know this is not what you ask, and as a practice and to learn how to code you should definitely proceed this way. But. When your app is growing it will become harder and harder to maintain, and you'll have to write a lot of complex code to implement features you'd want. You will have great benefit with using a framework, or maybe something like Wordpress will be enough. Just saying :)

Comment: Yes i know about frameworks. I would have used them if if i knew. But now it's a bit too late and btw my application is not getting too complex, moreover i am doing some refactoring because i have some free time, and it's the first web application i am doing. Everything is under control now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include HTML in files using PHP's `include()` function.

### Example using your provided HTML

form.php

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" class="big" style="display:none;">
<h3> Insert Contact </h3>
    <fieldset class="col2">
    <!-- Some inputs here -->
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clean Form">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="insert" value="1" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="modify" value="1" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="secret" value="<? echo($perm); ?>" class="hidden">
</form>
```

header.php

```
<div>Hello World!</div>
<?php $value = 10; ?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include(header.php); ?>
        <div>This is some content.  The number is <?php echo($value); ?></div>
        <?php include(form.php); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Output HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello World!</div>
        <div>This is some content.  The number is 10</div>
        <form action="insert.php" method="POST" class="big" style="display:none;">
        <h3> Insert Contact </h3>
        <fieldset class="col2">
        <!-- Some inputs here -->
        </fieldset>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Clean Form">
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="insert" value="1" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="modify" value="1" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="secret" value="<? echo($perm); ?>" class="hidden">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to choose between two different forms to include, you could do it using any of these methods:

### Method 1: Include the relevant form on different pages

insert.php

```
<?php include("insert-form.php"); ?>
```

edit.php

```
<?php include("edit-form.php"); ?>
```

### Method 2: Include the relevant form based on a conditional

index.php

```
<?php
$formchoose = "insert";

if($formchoose == "insert") {
    include("form-insert.php");
} else {
    include("form-default.php");
}
?>
```

### Method 3: Do the conditional in the include (this is the one you asked about in your comment)

index.php

```
<?php
$formchoose = "insert";
include(forms.php);
?>
```

forms.php

```
switch ($formchoose) {
    case "insert":
        ?>
            <form id="insert-form">
            <!-- form here-->
            </form>
        <?
    break;
    case "edit":
        ?>
            <form id="edit-form">
            <!-- form here-->
            </form>
        <?
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

### Documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: What about if i want to add just some parts of the include file? My worst nightmare are tons of files for the "include.php" all over the place. For example i could create a form.php where i can choose the content i want to take. But again i will end up in doing "echo"es.

Comment: You wont need echo for included HTML.  I updated the answer to show how you can include the form you posted in your question.  You can use different `include()` statements for different files.

Comment: What about to write, in form(s).php, other forms and giving some arguments to choose with? Like: if ($formchoose == "insert") then print form. But again.. with no echoes. Just the brackets { } will include all the things into it in automatic?

Comment: @MarkWuji sure, you can do that.  There are a few different methods to accomplish that.  I updated the answer that shows a few options.

Comment: Ok; so will it work this way? If so, that is what i was looking for, i will try, i didin't think that this could also have worked :)
But: don't you need to put a "break" after a "case"?

Comment: Yeah, you would need the break

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [PHP include()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php) (contains examples)

It's easy to use, you just have to write : `<?php include 'my_file.php'; ?>`

Since you can write html/js in a *.php* file, you can use it to include parts of your page.

Comment: I want to print different things in different pages. With that method it looks like i have to do files as much as the parts i need! And i can't really control the content...

Comment: @MarkWuji You can include the same file everywhere, with conditions inside that file to control the output, based on what page was loaded. You should in anyway note that `include` and `require` uses the server path, not the domain path.

Comment: You can try templating engines like Mustache https://github.com/janl/mustache.js. You'll have your page which is "the base" and JS will fill the gaps (You can do templating in PHP too, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/getting-started-with-php-templating/)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea which could help to make dynamic form:

**some_dynamic_form.php**

```
<?php
function getDynamic($form)
{
    switch ($form) {
        case 'form1':
            return array('hello', 'world', '1');
        case 'form2':
            return array('hello', 'from', '2');
    }
}

?>
```

index.html

```
<?php
require_once 'some_dynamic_form.php';
$dynamicForm = getDynamic('form1');
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#">
    <?php foreach ($dynamicForm as $param): ?>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $param ?>" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can make whatever you want with this to make it even better :) create a class of form so it will be OPP

Comment: I had a really similar idea, but the problem is, i don't want to use echo'es because of the brackets and because it looks really ugly, but i guess i don't have much choice...

Comment: you can always use a known MVC framework which may give you all the tool so the code looks readable (Recommendation - Laravel)

Comment: Well, adding a framework is maybe a little late now! Because i would have added it at first place if just i knew them! It is my first project so i wasn't ready for everything :)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using an MVC approach to separate your model (data), view, and controller (brains of your app).

You should also consider using a template engine such as Twig.